# Import JSON unnamed array from API in Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets

I wanted to import data from an API to a Google sheet, I found this: https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/

It requires a path in parameters, the problem is that my JSON start directly with an array like this:

```
[{...},{...}]
```

And I can't find what to put in the second parameter of the script that corresponds to that unnamed array.

I tried things like an empty field, or just a '/' but nothing seems to work, my sheet always returns an error.

Comment: can you tell what error is returned when you pass "/" ??

Comment: I don't know how to find errors in the sheet, but when i'm debugging the function it's blocking when it tries to get the attribute: 
for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
, it is returning "undefined" in the json variable.